# How do I fill absent on all days in an array till now which are not having the "Present" Element?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ajax, momentjs

**Let us assume the below as an array which consists of the attendance data of an employee (Fetched from Mongo using Ajax):**

```
[{"_id":"5fcdcd49c3657d1e05b846f5","title":"Present","allDay":true,"start":"2020-11-20","display":"background","color":"#4caf50"},
{"_id":"5fcdcd74c3657d1e05b846f6","title":"Present","allDay":true,"start":"2020-12-07","display":"background","color":"#4caf50"},
{"_id":"5fcebc7653057438acc633a6","title":"Present","allDay":true,"start":"2020-12-08","display":"background","color":"#4caf50"},]
```

This array consists of elements in JSON format.
**When the array is read we find that in every element, the JSON object contains two fields - Start (Which mentions the date) and Title (Which mentions whether the employee is present or absent)**

Now, We notice that On (2020-11-20) there is an element stating the employee is present. Then there is the next element stating that the employee is present on 2020-12-07 (About 17 days later). According to my use-case, I assume that the employee has been **Absent for these 17 days.**

Now,
These 17 days are -

- 2020-11-21
- 2020-11-22
- 2020-11-23
  ...
- till 2020-12-06

I would like to:

```
$.ajax(
{
url: "/api/employees/markAttendence/Absent/:date" [We will fill the date obviously, I have left it as :date for illustration]
type: "GET"
}
);
```

for every-day the employee is absent.

I wanted to use moment.js to subtract days from today, check whether an element is present with the date moment calculated. If there is no element I send the above Ajax request for that date.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much have you done so here we go begin with data processing.

With the given data, I would like to extract the start information into a array called `presentDate`.

```
var dataset = [{"_id":"5fcdcd49c3657d1e05b846f5","title":"Present","allDay":true,"start":"2020-11-20","display":"background","color":"#4caf50"},
               {"_id":"5fcdcd74c3657d1e05b846f6","title":"Present","allDay":true,"start":"2020-12-07","display":"background","color":"#4caf50"},
               {"_id":"5fcebc7653057438acc633a6","title":"Present","allDay":true,"start":"2020-12-08","display":"background","color":"#4caf50"},]

var presentDate = dataset.filter(data => data.title === "Present").map(data => data.start);
```

I try to work with `Moment.js`, and look back for about `30` days. To see if any date are exist in the `presentDate` and skip them.

```
var today = moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
var lookBackDays = 30;
var NeedToQuery = [];
for(var index = 1; index <= lookBackDays; ++index) {
    var checkDate = moment(today);
    checkDate.subtract(index, 'days');
    var dateString = checkDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    if(presentDate.indexOf(dateString) < 0)
    {
        // Here I store the date string into NeedToQuery
        NeedToQuery.push(dateString);
    }
}
```

Finally you would have date string to send the Ajax request, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank You @ian00!** I've also found a solution which works fine.

```
function markAbsentism() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/******/******/*******/",
          type: "GET",
        }).done((result) => {
          var presentDates = [],
            excludedDates = [];
          if (
            moment(result[result.length - 1].start).diff(
              moment(result[result.length - 2].start),
              "days"
            ) == 1 &&
            (result[result.length - 1].title == "Present" ||
              result[result.length - 1].title == "Absent") &&
            (result[result.length - 2].title == "Present" ||
              result[result.length - 2].title == "Absent")
          ) {
            console.log("IF_1 SUCCESS");
            return;
          } else {
            console.log("IF_1 FAILED");
            console.log("ELSE_1 EXEC STARTED");
            for (let ctr = result.length - 1; ctr >= 0; ctr--) {
              if (
                result[ctr].title == "Present"
              ) {
                if (presentDates.length <= 2) {
                  console.log("EMPLOYEE PRESENT");
                  presentDates.push(result[ctr].start);
                  excludedDates.push(result[ctr].start);
                } else {
                  console.log("GOT 2 PRESENT DATES. BREAKING LOOP");
                  break;
                }
              } else if (
                result[ctr].title == "Leave" ||
                result[ctr].title == "Holiday" ||
                result[ctr].title == "Half-Day"
              ) {
                console.log("EMPLOYEE IN LEAVE");
                excludedDates.push(result[ctr].start);
              }
            }
            console.log(presentDates);
            console.log(excludedDates);
          }

          console.log("Proceeding to For Loop");

          for (
            let i = 0;
            i <= moment(presentDates[0]).diff(moment(presentDates[1]), "days");
            i++
          ) {
            if (
              excludedDates.includes(
                moment(presentDates[1]).add(i, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
              )
            ) {
              console.log("EXCLUDED DATE CAUGHT CONTINUING");
              continue;
            } else {
              console.log("SENDING AJAX REQUEST");
              $.ajax({
                url:
                  "/******/******/*******/" +
                  moment(presentDates[1]).add(i, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                type: "GET",
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
```

I'll try even yours to find the most efficient one.